# Simple linux redirection

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, terminal

I am learning bash right now and I came across something I cannot understand. 
At this line:

`exec 3>&1 >log; echo 'Hello!'; exec 1>&3 3>&-`

Why is `1>&3` necessary at the end? If I exclude it it seems like everything I write in the terminal goes right into the log file. Why is `3>&-` not enough to close the FD?

It must be a dummy question but I've started learning so srry

Comment: This is definitely a link only comment, but it's a good resource to have; check out [ExplainShell's explanation](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=exec+3%3E%261+%3Elog%3B+echo+%27Hello!%27%3B+exec+1%3E%263+3%3E%26-).

Comment: I think the main point you're missing is when you do `3>&1`, file descriptor 3 does not get pointed to `fd 1`, it gets pointed to where `fd 1` is pointed. So `3>&-` is enough to close `fd 3`, but it has no impact on redirecting `fd 1` back to where it was originally pointed (i.e. `/dev/stdout`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    exec 3>&1 >log; echo 'Hello!'; exec 1>&3 3>&-
```

This line first saves stdout (1) to a new file descriptor (3), and creates file "log" and assigns it to stdout. Then, executes the echo with this setting, and restores the old stdout from descriptor 3, and cleans by closing the descriptor 3.

1>&3 restores the descriptor 1 by redirecting it to descriptor 3.

Note that, the effect of the redirections and opened/closed file descriptors by exec survives after the execution of it in the shell. Therefore the descriptor state should be restored to normal after whatever it is used for.

Also, note that, the order of the directions in both of the exec's matter. If you do it like:

```
    exec >log 3>&1; echo 'Hello!'; exec 1>&3 3>&-
```

or

```
    exec 3>&1 >log; echo 'Hello!'; exec 3>&- 1>&3
```

it won't work. In the first one, descriptor 3 will also direct to file "log", and descriptor 1 will be lost. In the second one, you will close the descriptor 3 before restoring it, and again descriptor 1 will be lost.